# "This is a case study on a course of general medicine." and "This is a case study in a course of general medicine"

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between "This is a case study on a course of general medicine." and "This is a case study in a course of general medicine". I see both usages, but I am thinking they mean completely different things. When we say "a case study on a course of general medicine", I think it means we're using the course of general medicine as a subject of the case study. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Case study* can take *on* or *about* for its complement, specifying the subject of the study. So "a case study on a course of general medicine" means that the course is the subject of the case study.

*Case study* does not have any special meaning for an *in* argument, so "in a course of general medicine" must be an adjunct, with *in* having its normal meaning: "a case study in a course of general medicine" means that the study appears or is studied or used in the course.